# Transforming an image using a known displacement field with imwarp in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, transformation

I wish to transform an image using a known displacement field but am having issues using the imwarp function for this. Any help would be very very appreciated

I use a grid in order to project an image onto a known plane. By detecting the location of the grid points in the image and comparing them to the location in "real" space I am able to come up with a matrix, D_OH, of size [m, n, 2] which represents the x and y displacements required. 
I use the line:

> OH_grid_avg_mapped = imwarp(OH_grid_avg_post, D_OH)

but get the following errors:

> Error using imwarp
>   Expected tform to be one of these types:
>
> images.geotrans.internal.GeometricTransformation
>
> Instead its type was double.
>
> Error in imwarp>validateTform (line 367)
>   validateattributes(t,{'images.geotrans.internal.GeometricTransformation'},{'scalar','nonempty'},'imwarp','tform');
>
> Error in imwarp>preparseSpatialReferencingObjects (line 384)
>       validateTform(tform);
>
> Error in imwarp (line 136)
>   [R_A, varargin] = preparseSpatialReferencingObjects(varargin{:});
>
> Error in VizExpt_SchlierenOHAlign_v7 (line 261)
>   OH_grid_avg_mapped = imwarp(OH_grid_avg_post, D_OH);"

Comment: Can you show what `D_OH` looks like? The third dimension (2) is suspicious :)

Comment: Hi Benoit, D_OH(:,:,1) describes the X component of additive displacement that is added to column and row locations in D to produce remapped locations in A. Similarly, D_OH(:,:,2) describes the Y component of additive displacement values

Comment: I've just noticed that I am using 2014a, not 2014b so perhaps that is the reason for my problems